# auto-complete field wordpress with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm doing a project on WordPress and I'm having some trouble with the auto-complete field on my form. No input is shown and no error in console. I created a small database on one of the WordPress database. I'm not very familiar with AJAX so please be kind :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

jQuery('#dish').autoComplete({
source: function(name, response) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: 'action=get_listing_names&name='+name,
        success: function(data) {
            response(data);
        }
    });
}
});

});
```

This is my jQuery code and I added the admin-ajax in the same folder as I was thinking it didn't find it (it's `my_serach.js`)

```
function ajax_listings() {
global $wpdb; //get access to the WordPress database object variable

//get names of all businesse
$name = $wpdb->esc_like(stripslashes($_POST['name'])).'%'; //escape for use in LIKE statement
$sql = "select name 
    from $wpdb->global 
    where name like %s 
    and post_type='portfolio' and post_status='publish'";

$sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $name);
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

//copy the business titles to a simple array
$titles = array();
foreach( $results as $r )
    $titles[] = addslashes($r->name );

echo json_encode($titles); //encode into JSON format and output
die(); //stop "0" from being output
```

i add this code on the `functions.php` on the theme i'm working on

```
 <form method = "POST">
    <div id = "container">
        <div><label class="plate_label">Dish:</label><input type="text"    name="dish_name[]" id="dish" class="dish" placeholder="Enter plate name" />
            <label class="quantity_label">Quantity:</label><input type="text" name="dish_quantity[]"  class="quantity" placeholder="Enter gram or pieces/slices" /></div>
        </div>
```

and last the form where it should show the suggestions from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

jQuery('#dish').autoComplete({
    source: function(name, response) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://caloriless.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: 'action=get_listing_names&name='+name,
        success: function(data) {
        response(data);
        }
    });
    }
});
```

});

change ajax url `url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',` or `url: 'http://caloriless.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',`

Comment: still not working :( not showing any suggestion. and no errors in console. is the PHP alright like that?

Comment: Did you use this script in js file or PHP file?

Comment: js file. and the PHP code I added in the functions file at the bottom. I even tried to add two alerts in the js file, one at the beginning and one at the end and both of them are showing.

Comment: You need to replace this in your ajax ' url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'

Comment: do I need to add any PHP reference in the form? like an action on the dish field? I followed this tutorial to create the code https://davidnash.com.au/create-an-auto-complete-field-in-wordpress/

Comment: No. You need to change in ajax URL in auto complete ajax url

Comment: still not. just to be clear so the jquery has to be add in a separate file in a directory like js/my-js.js and the php has to be add in the functions. php right?

Comment: Please share me your site url

Comment: what is the site url?

Comment: http://caloriless.com/index.php/calories-calculator/ sorry for the design but I'm still working on that

Comment: I don't think can be the database. I created a simple MySQL database with id name and kilocal and when I use it for the output of the form it works.

Comment: i checked your site. seems ajax url is wrong. its getting 404 error.

Comment: I updated my answer please check the updated answer.

Comment: ok, I change it and no more 404 error. about the PHP code for the database, my database as password and admin name, do I need to do a mysqli connection to the database or the wpdb connect directly to it?

Comment: Wpdb is correct. Did you print the SQL query? If no print the query and execute the query in database. What is returned the query?